# Elixir/Phoenix date from weekday + weeknumber

Tags: date, elixir, phoenix-framework

Is it possible to get date (day, month, year) by providing week number and weekday? Basically I need query for this week's monday.

I've checked Erlang, there is `:erlang.date |> :calendar.day_of_the_week` which returns the weekday. However, is there a way to reverse this function? Provide weekday, week number and year to get the exact date?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically I need query for this week's monday.

You can compare the date's day_of_the_week against the day_of_the_week of Monday (1) and subtract that many days from the date:

```
def monday_in_the_week_of(date) do
  from_monday = :calendar.day_of_the_week(date) - 1
  date
  |> :calendar.date_to_gregorian_days
  |> Kernel.-(from_monday)
  |> :calendar.gregorian_days_to_date
end
```

Demo:

```
defmodule A do
  def monday_in_the_week_of(date) do
    from_monday = :calendar.day_of_the_week(date) - 1
    date
    |> :calendar.date_to_gregorian_days
    |> Kernel.-(from_monday)
    |> :calendar.gregorian_days_to_date
  end
end

for d <- 1..15 do
  date = {2017, 2, d}
  IO.inspect {date, A.monday_in_the_week_of(date)}
end
```

Output:

```
{{2017, 2, 1}, {2017, 1, 30}}
{{2017, 2, 2}, {2017, 1, 30}}
{{2017, 2, 3}, {2017, 1, 30}}
{{2017, 2, 4}, {2017, 1, 30}}
{{2017, 2, 5}, {2017, 1, 30}}
{{2017, 2, 6}, {2017, 2, 6}}
{{2017, 2, 7}, {2017, 2, 6}}
{{2017, 2, 8}, {2017, 2, 6}}
{{2017, 2, 9}, {2017, 2, 6}}
{{2017, 2, 10}, {2017, 2, 6}}
{{2017, 2, 11}, {2017, 2, 6}}
{{2017, 2, 12}, {2017, 2, 6}}
{{2017, 2, 13}, {2017, 2, 13}}
{{2017, 2, 14}, {2017, 2, 13}}
{{2017, 2, 15}, {2017, 2, 13}}
```

Comment: Hey @Dogbert, thanks for your solution, everything works now!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get date (day, month, year) by providing week number and weekday?

Maybe something like this would work:

```
@doc """
iex>get_date(1, 1, 2018)
{:ok, ~D[2018-01-01]}
"""
def get_date(weekday, _week_number, _year)
    when weekday < 1 or weekday > 7,
    do: {:error, "invalid weekday: #{inspect(weekday)}"}

def get_date(_weekday, week_number, _year)
    when week_number < 0 or week_number > 51,
    do: {:error, "invalid week_number: #{inspect(week_number)}"}

def get_date(weekday, week_number, year) do
  case Date.new(year, 1, 1) do
    {:ok, first_day_of_year} ->
      Date.add(first_day_of_year, week_number * 7 + weekday - 1)

    {:error, error} ->
      {:error, error}
  end
end
```